# Undergraduate maths research

Tags: undergraduate-education, education-research, undergraduate-research

I am looking for:

- an undergraduate research program
- in mathematics/theoretical physics
- offered online (e.g. via skype or something)
- given by a good institution
- which can be followed while attending another university
- which provides material for further study relevant to research
- which lasts for a minimum of two months

The last two criteria are not strictly necessary.  Does such a program exist?

Comment: It is an interesting idea to try to satisfy your first and third bullet, here. Having supervised many undergrad research projects, though, I find that a lot of information is conveyed face-to-face. My summer undergraduate researchers work with together with me for four hours each morning and write for four more hours every afternoon. This goes on for 6 straight weeks. It seems that a lot of habits are picked up through this close, sustained "apprenticeship". I can't imagine it would work virtually...but who knows! Good luck!

Comment: Somewhat as in @JonBannon's comment, it is completely unclear what "research program" could mean (at an entry level) while meeting your constraints. What do you mean by "research"? If it means simply "self-guided inquiry", without qualification about making a genuine contribution to current science, that's one thing. If it includes getting up to speed on contemporary math/phys from scratch (=undergrad level) this might be much harder to do under your constraints.

Comment: Though you might not be able to do it online, the Caltech SURF program can be pretty flexible. i.e. I meet with my adviser once a week, but it could probably be done entirely via Skype if you have a professor that is willing to do that.